# Controlled U gate with multiple control qubits

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

How do I implement a 3xControlled U gate with different control states in Qiskit?

The standard circuit.cu() funktion does not implement multiple control qubits in this way but just creates sequential U gates.

I have seen this post on [StackExchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/implementing-a-controlled-controlled-u-using-controlled-u) but don't really know how to translate it into different control states and would still prefer an implementation without additional helper qubits since I try to rebuild this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.05475).

[image: the target circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In qiskit you have the ControlledGate class:

https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.ControlledGate.html

In order to have different control states, just prepend an $X$ gate where necessary.

Comment: Thanks! With that I found my solution in: 
c3u_gate = UGate(0.1,0,0).control(3, ctrl_state="100")